# What is the Difference between Various Kalman Filters?

Tags: reference-request, signal-processing, control-theory, bayesian-network, kalman-filter

What is the difference between additive and multiplicative kalman filters, as well as some other kinds?

I'm also looking for reference texts and articles that describe the algorithms, so recommendations for those as well would be preferable.

Comment: Maybe this is more suited to http://dsp.stackexchange.com ?